# Why are some photos grainy in Chrome and Brave but not Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, photos, hardware-acceleration, brave

As an example, when I open [rickbern.com](https://rickbern.com/) in Chrome or Brave under default settings, some of the headshots are displayed as grainy or speckled.  In Chrome:

[image: grainy headshots in Chrome]

In Brave:

[image: grainy headshots in Brave]

However, in Firefox, these same images are pristine:

[image: pristine headshots in Firefox]

If I turn off hardware acceleration in Chrome (by going to Settings, searching for "hardware," turning off the option "Use hardware acceleration when available," and relaunching Chrome), the images are significantly improved, but in fact still show the same graininess or speckling on a lower level (perhaps most visibly in the hair):

[image: slightly grainy headshots in Chrome]

Broadly, what is the underlying source of the graininess in Chrome and Brave, and how can I fix it?

---

If somehow relevant, I am viewing these images on a Dell Precision 3541 running Windows 10.  The screen is 15.6" FHD WVA (1920x1080).

Comment: Probably a combination of multiple factors, but most importantly: The images are actually gigantic. On the front page, they’re scaled to ~15% on my screen.

Comment: Good point.  Still, the comparison to Firefox suggests that the graininess isn't a necessary consequence of the size.  What is Firefox doing differently?

Comment: On my computer there is no difference between Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Hmm, the plot thickens.  I have added my system information to the question in case it is relevant.